# Trying to transmit a 1 by 4 array message to subscriber

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble trying to publish correctly a 1 by 4 array message generated using a for loop based on test data. My system is a ubuntu 16.04 running Kinetic.
The error occurred in the pub.publish(message) line. Below is my code:

```
# Import Packages
import sys

sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

from raisim_gym.algo.ppo2 import PPO2
import os
import math
import argparse
import pickle

def action2Thrust(mylist):       
    _actionMean = 2.5
    _actionStd = 2
        
    Newthrust = mylist.astype(float)*_actionStd
    Newthrust += _actionMean
    return Newthrust


# Have to add the path again so that import rospy works. 
sys.path.append('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from transmit_thrust.msg import ThrustAction


# Function to map the action value to true thrust range none negative to the range between 
# 0.5 to 4.5 scale

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # configuration
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-w', '--weight', help='trained weight path', type=str, default='')
        args = parser.parse_args()

        weight_path = args.weight
    
        if weight_path == "":
            print("Can't find trained weight, please provide a trained weight with --weight switch\n")

        else:

            print("Loaded weight from {}\n".format(weight_path))
            model = PPO2.load(weight_path)

         # Needed to load observations here to test this script would be using pickle here
            with open('/home/ted/raisim_workspace/raisimGym/scripts/obArray.pickle', 'rb') as f:
                obs = pickle.load(f)
         # Needed to instantiate an array to save Thrust for outputting         
            ThrustArray = ThrustAction()
            pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', ThrustAction, queue_size=10)
            rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
            rate = rospy.Rate(100) # 10hz

            for i in range(len(obs)):

                action, _ = model.predict(obs[i])
                # print("Action: {}".format(action))
        
                Thrust = action2Thrust(action)
                # print("Thrust: {}".format(Thrust))

                ThrustArray = Thrust
            
                while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                    rospy.loginfo(ThrustArray)
                    pub.publish(ThrustArray)
                    rate.sleep()

    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

The obs obtain a set of test data in a large array in the form of 18 by 47093, which is 18 columns and 47093 rows. The arrays are fed into a for loop generating individual thrust command of 1 by 4 which are published to the subscriber node.
I have tried to replace the line:

```
ThrustArray = Thrust
```

to

```
ThrustArray.action = Thrust
```

where action is the attribute of ThrustArray.msg which is defined as a float32[].
Below is the error output：

```
[INFO] [1569343371.533475]: [[0.5
3.76598799 0.6819396 0.91531122]] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transmit_thrust/msg/_ThrustAction.py", line 55, in serialize buff.write(struct.pack(pattern, *self.action)) struct.error: required argument is not a float

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 882, in publish self.impl.publish(data) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1066, in publish serialize_message(b, self.seq, message) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message msg.serialize(b) File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transmit_thrust/msg/_ThrustAction.py", line 56, in serialize except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self))))) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 334, in _check_types check_type(n, t, getattr(self, n)) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 254, in check_type raise SerializationError('field %s must be a list or tuple type'%field_name) genpy.message.SerializationError: field action must be a list or tuple type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/transmit_thrust/scripts/transmitThrust.py", line 108, in <module> pub.publish(ThrustArray) File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 886, in publish raise ROSSerializationException(str(e)) rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: field action must be a list or tuple type
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with how I am defining my custom message of a 1 by 4 array? Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333822/trying-to-transmit-a-1-by-4-array-message-to-subscriber/) by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-09-24**:
Ok, so what returns `model.predict(obs[i])`? It seems to me it is a numpy array, as you use `astype(float)` laster on with it, right? And what exactly is your message definition? Since you asked, if there is something wrong with defining your custom message

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
Hi LeoE,

Yes you are right, model.predict(obs[i])  returns a 1 by 4 numpy array in the form like [1 1 -1 -1], where the numbers are in between -1 to 1. It could have many decimal places that's why I assigned ThrustAction.msg as following:

```
float32[] action
```

where action is the attribute of ThrustAction as my custom message file. I did this following this question on stackflow [Publishing Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369934/ros-publishing-array-from-python-node)

It seemed to me the resulting output ThrustAction had two square brackets but I only needed one to be a list. I am not sure why this is. Or it could be that I needed to assign float64[] instead, but I highly doubt it.

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
I think it's highly likely that I needed to numpize my array before publishing since as LeoE pointed out that my arrays are numpy arrays not lists. So I will follow the tutorial here and see if it works:
[Numpize Array](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All you need to do is convert your numpy array to a python list and assign it to your message.action.
This means replace the line `ThrustArray = Thrust` with (as you tried before) `ThrustArray.action = list(Thrust)`. This should do the trick. This works since you know, that Thrust is a 1D array making the numpy-array to list conversion rather easy.

---

Originally posted by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) with karma: 196 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
@LeoE
Thanks for the reply, at least the list error is gone but I got the following error output:

```
 [INFO] [1569374940.181282]: action: 
  - [0.5        3.78099775 0.5        1.07836843]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transmit_thrust/msg/_ThrustAction.py", line 55, in serialize
    buff.write(struct.pack(pattern, *self.action))
struct.error: required argument is not a float
```

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 882, in publish
self.impl.publish(data)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1066, in publish
serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
msg.serialize(b)
File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/transmit_thrust/msg/_ThrustAction.py", line 56, in serialize
except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(locals().get('_x', self)))))
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 336, in _check_types
raise SerializationError(str(exc))
genpy.message.SerializationError: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'action:

- [0.5        3.78099775 0.5        1.07836843]'

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/transmit_thrust/scripts/transmitThrust.py", line 108, in <module>
    pub.publish(ThrustArray)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 886, in publish
    raise ROSSerializationException(str(e))
rospy.exceptions.ROSSerializationException: <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing 'action: 
  - [0.5        3.78099775 0.5        1.07836843]'
```

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
This is my current code for the same error:

```
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        for i in range(len(obs)):

            action, _ = model.predict(obs[i])
            # print("Action: {}".format(action))

            Thrust = action2Thrust(action)
            # print("Thrust: {}".format(Thrust))

            ThrustArray.action = list(Thrust)
        
            rospy.loginfo(ThrustArray)
            pub.publish(ThrustArray)
            rate.sleep()
```

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-24**:
Here are some of the output I have for data types:

```
Thrust is type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
ThrustArray is type: <class 'transmit_thrust.msg._ThrustAction.ThrustAction'>
ThrustArray.action is type: <class 'list'>
[INFO] [1569379841.331428]: [array([0.5       , 3.83800876, 0.71245861, 0.77146018])]
Thrust is type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
ThrustArray is type: <class 'transmit_thrust.msg._ThrustAction.ThrustAction'>
ThrustArray.action is type: <class 'list'>
[INFO] [1569379841.341008]: [array([0.5       , 3.90113711, 0.7153132 , 0.95803189])]
```

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-09-24**:
@haloted Please don't use comments to post code/terminal output, please update your question instead. It's easier to keep track of the question that way

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-09-25**:
This is because your numpy array is actually a ndarray. In this case use numpys `tolist()` function:
`ThrustArray.action = Thrust.tolist()`

**Comment by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on 2019-09-25**:
@LeoE:
Yes it now works with tolist(). Sorry that I am kind of new to python.